# Extracting LinkedIn profile names with email address of all US IT professionals

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm working on project that using LinkedIn developer account. How can I extract all IT professionals email address through LinkedIn using LinkedIn API?

Answer (score 0):

- For country, you could check Location Fields in [this page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/location) for API information regarding LinkedIn
- For contact information, I am not sure whether LinkedIn provides access to email address, you could refer to [this page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/contact) for API information for contact details